# How do I make this counters start from 2.01 and say something at the end of counting

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to make a counter that will always start from 2.01 and count upwards to a set limit that I will assign $limit and when it reaches the $limit it should say '$limit is the maximum' eg 31.23 is the maximum in red

```js
function startCounter(){
    $('.counter').each(function (index) {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 8000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(parseFloat(now).toFixed(2));
            }
        });
    });
}
 startCounter();
```

```css
   
.counter{
    font-size: 30px;
    COLOR: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter">300.1</div>
```

Comment: You have put `startCounter();` in the CSS box in the snippet. If you move that into the JavaScript box and also put a <script> element which brings JQuery library in then your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```js
function startCounter(){
    $('.counter').each(function (index) {
        $(this).prop('Counter',2.01).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 100000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(parseFloat(now).toFixed(2));
            }
        });
    });
}   

startCounter();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="counter">31.23</span>
```